# Get next from previous tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, drop-down-menu

I have different `<select>` with proper `id` attribute. Under each `<select>` there is an `<a>` tag with no proper `id` or `class`.
I can't add an `id` to the `<a>` tag because it's generated by a jQuery lib.

Example:

```
<select class="foo" id="foo">
..
</select>
<a class="same" href="#">link</a>
<select class="bar" id="bar">
..
</select>
<a class="same" href="#">link</a>
```

There is a way to get the first `<a>` tag under a specific `<select>` tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anchor tag is going to be immediate next sibling, You can use `.next()` selector:

```
 $('#foo').next();
```

Otherwise you need to use `.nextAll()` with `.first()`:

```
 $('#foo').nextAll('a').first();
```

Answer (score 0):

**Hello!**

Vanilla JS solution:

**One selector:**

```
document.querySelector('select').nextElementSibling;
```

**Example:**

```js
document.querySelector('select').nextElementSibling.style.color = 'red';
```

```html
<select class="foo" id="foo">
  </select>
<a class="same" href="#">link</a>
<select class="bar" id="bar">
  </select>
<a class="same" href="#">link</a>
```

---

**Multi selectors:**

```
document.querySelectorAll('select');
```

**Example:**

```js
var arr = document.querySelectorAll('select');

for (var i = 0, length1 = arr.length; i < length1; i++) {
  arr[i].nextElementSibling.style.color = 'red';
}
```

```html
<select class="foo" id="foo">
  </select>
<a class="same" href="#">link</a>
<select class="bar" id="bar">
  </select>
<a class="same" href="#">link</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try use jQuery find.

```
$( "select" ).find( "a" );
```

Comment: `.find()` searches all descendants of an element and the anchors in the code are siblings, not descendants.